# I have a graphQL query and wanted to convert it GraphQL Transformer v1 to v2

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify, graphql-js, typegraphql, aws-amplify-sdk-js

I was working on an existing project using amplify with GraphQl API.

The query shows issues with @Key as `Your GraphQL Schema is using "@key" directive from an older version of the GraphQL Transformer` . Since I am new to graphQL, what should I change to make this work?

Thanks

**Error:**

```
✖ An error occurred when pushing the resources to the cloud
 An error occurred during the push operation: Your GraphQL Schema is using "@key" directive from an older version of the GraphQL Transformer. Visit https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/migration/transformer-migration/ to learn how to migrate your GraphQL schema.
```

**Query:**

```
type KeyValuePair {
    key: String!
    value: String
}

type Template
  @model
  @auth(rules: [ {allow: owner } ]) {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  description: String
  provision_style: String!
  status: String!
  params: [KeyValuePair]
  resources: [KeyValuePair]
}

type Asset
  @model
  @auth(rules: [ {allow: owner } ]) 
  @key(name: "categoryTypeIndex", fields: ["category", "type"], queryField: "assetsByCategoryAndType")
  @key(name: "categoryNameIndex", fields: ["category", "name"], queryField: "assetsByCategoryAndName")
  @key(name: "categoryStatusIndex", fields: ["category", "status"], queryField: "assetsByCategoryAndStatus") {
  id: ID!
  parent: ID
  category: String!
  type: String!
  name: String!
  description: String
  status: String
  template: String
  details: [KeyValuePair]
}

type Contract
  @model
  @auth(rules: [ {allow: owner } ]) 
  @key(name: "tenantAssetIndex", fields: ["tenantId", "assetId"], queryField: "contractsByTenantAndAsset")
  @key(name: "tenantNameIndex", fields: ["tenantId", "name"], queryField: "contractsByTenantAndName")
  @key(name: "tenantStatusIndex", fields: ["tenantId", "status"], queryField: "contractsByTenantAndStatus") {
  id: ID!
  type: String!
  tenantId: String!
  assetId: String!
  name: String!
  description: String
  status: String
  details: [KeyValuePair]
  resources: [KeyValuePair]
}

type PlatformEvent
  @model
  @auth(rules: [ {allow: owner } ]) 
  @key(name: "contractTypeIndex", fields: ["contractId", "type"], queryField: "eventsByContractAndType")
  @key(name: "contractSourceIndex", fields: ["contractId", "sourceId"], queryField: "eventsByContractAndSource")
  @key(name: "sourceTypeIndex", fields: ["sourceId", "type"], queryField: "eventsBySourceAndType") {
  id: ID!
  type: String!
  contractId: String!
  sourceId: String!
  content: String!
  details: [KeyValuePair]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS provides a migration guide: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/migration/transformer-migration/ but unfortunately they don't specify how to actually set your API to use the new/old version.

If you look in your `amplify` folder you will find a `cli.json` file, to set your backend to use version 1 of the GraphQLTransformer you simply need to edit the file and set the following two properties:

```
  "features": {
    "graphqltransformer": {
      ...
      "useexperimentalpipelinedtransformer": false,
      "transformerversion": 1,
      ...
    },
```

From there you simply `amplify push` and assuming you've catered for all of the changes the migration guide describes it will update your endpoint correctly.

EDIT: For those looking to upgrade to V2 instead of downgrading to V1 you will need to set the properties as follows:

```
  "features": {
    "graphqltransformer": {
      ...
      "useexperimentalpipelinedtransformer": true,
      "transformerversion": 2,
      ...
    },
```

Comment: Solution does not work because on amplify push - the cli.json gets automatically updated to 2

Comment: It didn't at the time of posting my answer, I would recommend reading the docs and seeing which version of amplify they introduced this in and either setting a config to disable it (if available) or downgrading Amplify until you are ready to upgrade...

Answer (score -1):

[This](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-amplify/graphql-transformer-migrator/v/1.2.26) should make your life easy.

Comment: Getting the same issue:

Comment: ranopriyo.neogy@ranopriyoneogy-MacBook-Pro platform-assets % amplify migrate api                     
 Your GraphQL Schema is using "@key" directive from an older version of the GraphQL Transformer. Visit https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/migration/transformer-migration/ to learn how to migrate your GraphQL schema.
dProject (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-provider-awscloudformation/src/graphql-transformer/transform-graphql-schema.ts:562:37)

Comment: Please elaborate when creating an answer. Simply linking to a page is lazy.